# Adding a 2-degree downward slope for an apartment building roof

Tags: surface-deform

Hello Blender community,

I have an apartment building which has been extruded with a flat roof. I have added five cuts with the knife tool and want to be able to vertically raise or drop the intersection point in order to create a gradual (2 degree) slope in the roof. However, Blender does not recognize the intersection point and only identifies four separate faces. How can I create a roof with a 2 degree slope in four directions? Each of the separate triangular segments must to have a downward 2 degree slope in the direction of the red dot intersection point.

Should I create four separate extruded faces and slope them one-by-one? Should I work with a single extrusion and use the knife tool? Should I add a new work plane on the top of the roof and try using that? Lastly, I used the knife tool on simple cube in a new Blender window and the four-way cut and move command at the intersection point worked fine. This is driving me crazy and I would really appreciate any help.[image]

Comment: "normally" 3 knife cuts (2 diagonal and the vertical) should be enough and then you should be able to lift the middle vertex as you wanted. If that doesn't work, can u please create a short screencast video so we can see what you did? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chozw.gif

Answer (score 1):

If the whole roof is supposed to be sloped, you can use another (pyramidal) object as *Boolean* object, make sure that the normals of this object are pointing downwards:

[image]

Lower down the boolean object in order to get your sloped roof:

[image]

Apply the *Boolean* modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you've used a knife tool there. Just selecting a vertex at opposing corners of the plane and hitting 'J' then doing the same with the other corners should produce your four triangles with a single vertex at the centre. You'd then just need to select the centre vertex where they all join, hit G > Z and move it up. Work out how much you need to move it up using trigonometry. (Mine's very rusty because I haven't needed it for around 60 years so I'l leave that excercise to you!)

[image]